# How to create log file frontend angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services, frontend

How to create log file frontend angular? I want create new file log when start new date. 
Example: 
log_20181128.log 
log_20181129.log 
log_20181130.log 
Thank every body for your help!

Comment: You want to write a log file on the client's computer?

Comment: I have a angular module. My job is to create a log for it and save it to that module. Examples: Save communication (send / receive, date and time) with Report Service(nodejs) in log file.